# pgfplots - draw boxplot without outliers

Tags: pgfplots, statistics, boxplot

I am creating a `boxplot` with `pgfplots`, using the builtin `statistics` library. I load the input data from a table file.

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
...
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[boxplot/draw direction=y]
   \addplot+[boxplot] table[
     col sep=tab,
     x expr=\coordindex,
     y=aColName] {aFileName};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is it possible to draw the plot without outliers? Or hide them? I don't want to pre-calculate the `boxplot` values by hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add the following code snippet to your preamble, you can use `hide outliers` to locally disable plotting the outliers:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    boxplot/hide outliers/.code={
        \def\pgfplotsplothandlerboxplot@outlier{}%
    }
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    boxplot/hide outliers/.code={
        \def\pgfplotsplothandlerboxplot@outlier{}%
    }
}
\makeatother


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y=1cm, try min ticks=2]
\addplot+[boxplot]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
21\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y=1cm, try min ticks=2]
% somewhen the simple statement of `hide outliers` broke.
% Now the full path to the style needs to be written.
\addplot+[boxplot, /pgfplots/boxplot/hide outliers]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
21\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried your sample both on my local Latex as well as on Overleaf and I always get `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/hide outliers' and I amd going to ignore it`.

Comment: You can also do `boxplot={hide outliers}` or stick `boxplot/hide outliers` into the optional arguments of `axes`, instead of using `boxplot, /pgfplots/boxplot/hide outliers`

Comment: This does not seem to work with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`...

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness here is a solution using the combination of 'R-knitr-LaTeX'.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
<<echo=FALSE>>=
#par(pin=c(5,.1))
#par(mar=c(.2,.2,.2,.2))
par(bty="n")
#par(mai=c(.35,.35,.35,.35),omi=c(0,0,0,0))
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
x=c(1,2,1,5,4,10,7,10,9,8,9,9,21)
boxplot(x,horizontal=TRUE,outline=TRUE,plot=TRUE,axes=TRUE)
axis(side=1, at=c(0,5,10,15,20))
boxplot(x,horizontal=TRUE,outline=FALSE,plot=TRUE, col='lightblue',axes=TRUE)
axis(side=1, at=c(0,2,4,6,8,10))
@
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have simply done that by just adding `mark=none` to `\addplot+[boxplot]`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[boxplot/draw direction=y,]

\addplot+[boxplot]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
    7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
    21\\
};

% box plot without outliers
\addplot+[boxplot, mark=none]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
    data\\
    1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
    7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
    21\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a valid solution. The marks are not drawn, but still considered for the y-axis. So in the example, even if only the red boxplot is drawn the y-axis would still reach past 20, leaving half the plot empty